# Check email exists in mysql database or not with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Need to check email is exists or not in mysql when user enters in the form.
From form requser.email will have user emaild entered in form. How to compare requser.email with database to find match.

```
 router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    var requser = req.body.data.user;
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.data.user.password)
  var str = "";

  /*email check start*/

  /*email check end*/
  switch (requser.role) {
    case "approver":
      str = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password,role) values("' + requser.name + '","' + requser.email + '","' + hash + '","approver")';
      break;
    case "user":
      str = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password,role) values("' + requser.name + '","' + requser.email + '","' + hash + '","user")';
      break;
    case "admin":
      str = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password,role) values("' + requser.name + '","' + requser.email + '","' + hash + '","admin")';
      break;
  }
  if (!str) {
    return res.json({
      "status": "error",
      "data": {
        "redirect": "/"
      }
    });
  }
  connection.query(str, function(error, rows) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error ocurred", error);
    }
    //console.log(rows);
    res.json({
      "status": error ? "error" : "success",
      "data": rows || ""
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **WARNING**: To avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) always escape *any* arbitrary data in your query by using [placeholder values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values). This login system allows anyone to do *anything* with your site and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write a `SELECT 1` query to get the record with that email address or define a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on email field so that insert would fail.

[Here's](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) an example of `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and here's an example of `SELECT 1`:

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = <email>;
```

Comment: `$email` is a PHP thing. This is a Node question.