# How do I check whether email already exist in mysql db using nodejs express

Tags: mysql, node.js, validation, express

I've written the code for registration in nodejs following is my code. I want to check whether the email already exist in db.If so then show error in client side.I'm using react native as front end.Following is my code.

```
users.post('/registration', function(req,res){

      var today = new Date();
        var appData = {
          "error" :"1",
          "data" : "",
          "userData" :"",
        };

        var userData = {
          "pwd"      :  req.body.password,
          "phone_no" :  req.body.contact,
          "user_name":  "" ,
          "status"   :  1,
          "date"     :  today,

        }

        database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection){
          if(err){
            appData["error"] =1;
            appData["data"]  = "Internal Server Error";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
          } else{
          connection.query("INSERT INTO user_registration SET ?" ,userData, function(err,result,fields){

            var phone = userData.phone_no;
            connection.query("SELECT user_id from user_registration WHERE phone_no=?", [phone], function(err,result,fields){
               if(!err){
                 appData.error= 0;
                 appData["data"] = "User registered Successfully";
                 appData["userData"] = userData;
                 appData["user_id"] =result[0].user_id;
                 let token = jwt.sign(result[0], process.env.SECRET_KEY);
                 appData["token"] =token;
                 res.status(201).json(appData);
               } else{
                 appData["data"] = "Error Occured";
                 res.status(400).json(appData);

               }
               console.log(appData);
             });
            });
                  connection.release();
          }
        });

   });
```

Comment: You need to mention what is the step where you are having issue?

Comment: How do I check whether email already exist in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check email exists in mysql database or not with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006767/check-email-exists-in-mysql-database-or-not-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way .. Before insert data you have to check email exist or not

```
connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tableName WHERE email = ? " , 
body.email , function(err , data){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   }   
   else{
       if(data[0].cnt > 0){  
             // Already exist 
       }else{
           connection.query("INSERT INTO ..." , function(err , insert){
               if(err){
                   // retunn error
               }else{
                   // return success , user will insert 
               }
           })                  
       }
   }
})
```

Comment: Nice SQL injection vector you have there.

Comment: @robertklep I know , But I was just showing the path, Now I have update my answer to protect `SQL injection` with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MySQL with express js and this worked for me.
if it helps anyone

```js
const user = await Users.findAll({
  where: {
    email: req.body.email,
  },
});
    
if (user[0]) {
  return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Email already exist" });
}
```