# Check if email already exist in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, email

How can I check if an email already is in Mysql database on NodeJs?
I'm using the following code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
router.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/html/index.html'));
    var email = req.query.email;
    if (email != null) {
        conn.query('INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)', [email], function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('1 record inserted')            
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: make the column unique, it is the easiest and best way

Comment: Hello check this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185976/19360213 I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check whether email already exist in mysql db using nodejs express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185875/how-do-i-check-whether-email-already-exist-in-mysql-db-using-nodejs-express)

Comment: @nbk make the column unique and catch the error it will generate and present it correctly to the user.

Comment: @ysth he catches already the error and how to make a column unique can be found thousand fold

Comment: @nbk catches and rethrows, likely showing a 500 page; that's very different from detecting a unique key constraint failure and formatting a friendly error message in just that case

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from a store stay project I had.
I use this method because it is convenient for me.

```
const [isItemExist] = await SQL(`
    SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.id =${Item} `)
    

    if (!isItemExist) {
        return res.send({ err: 'product not found' })
    }
```

Comment: this is a terrible solution, on heavy duty servers this will fail

Comment: @nbk why would it be a terrible solution?

Comment: on heavy duty servers you get that the email doesn't exist and in the time the emal could be already inserted. there are hundreds of threads because of this solution

Answer (score 0):

Check if e-mail exist only do insert if it doesn't:

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/html/index.html'));
            var email = req.query.email;
    
            if (email != null) {
            conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?', [email], function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    console.log('Email already exist')
                }
                else {
                    conn.query('INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)', [email], function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('1 record inserted')
                    })}
                })
            }
        })
```